# Can not store double value properly into MySQL 5.7.25 after load dump of MySQL 5.7.24

Tags: mysql

How can I store double value properly in `MySQL 5.7.25`?

I had dump from Valentian DB of `MySQL 5.7.24` and loaded in `MySQL 5.7.25`.

**For example:** Storing 10.20 store only 10 in loaded dump tables but I can store 10.20 properly into newly created tables in `MySQL 5.7.25`.

> When I print value `System.out.println("Amt: "+ cost);`
>   output: 10.20.
>   Even entity field `System.out.println(receivings.getWholesalePrice());`
>    return same value "10.20" so where is the problem?

Is it bug or do I need to recreate tables in `MySQL 5.7.25`?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are doing? How are you storing anything? By running a query- which one?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate I'm not using query, using session.save(entityObject); But I don't think this is matter cause I can store using same code and with desired output.

Comment: I've reloaded dump but it doesn't work I'll recreate table and will check. Thank you.